# What does tf.gfile do in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've seen people using several functions from `tf.gfile` such as `tf.gfile.GFile` or `tf.gfile.Exists`. I have the idea that `tf.gfile` deals with files. However, I haven't been able to find the official documentation to see what else it offers.

It'd be great if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 48):

For anyone landing here, the following answer was provided (by a googler) on: [Why use tensorflow gfile? (for file I/O)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922948/why-use-tensorflow-gfile-for-file-i-o/)

> The main roles of the tf.gfile module are:
>
> 1. To provide an API that is close to Python's file objects, and
> 2. To provide an implementation based on TensorFlow's C++ FileSystem API.
>
> The C++ FileSystem API supports multiple file system implementations,
>   including local files, Google Cloud Storage (using a `gs://` prefix),
>   and HDFS (using an `hdfs://` prefix). TensorFlow exports these as
>   `tf.gfile`, so that you can use these implementations for saving and
>   loading checkpoints, writing TensorBoard logs, and accessing training
>   data (among other uses). However, if all of your files are local, you
>   can use the regular Python file API without any problem.

Comment: I still dont get it though. Cant you just use with `open(file_name, 'w') as f:`?

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura, yes you can. gfile is only required if you would like to use a less-convensional filesystem, such as "google cloud storage"

Comment: @Chaine I think it's much easier to use tf.gfile if you want to debug your model locally and train it on cloud. Then, you don't have to change a single line.

Comment: @YuvalAtzmon : So, like if I want to use HDFS for parallelization, then I'd have to use tf.gfile with tensorflow, is that correct and also for using Google Cloud Storage with tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly point out `tf.gfile` is an abstraction for accessing the filesystem and is documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile). It is recommended over using plain python API since it provides some level of portability.

Comment: I still dont get it though. Cant you just use `with open(file_name, 'w') as f:`? What do you mean by some level of portability?

Comment: Depending on your usage, the relevant documentation might actually be under [tf.io.gfile](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile)