# Why use tensorflow gfile? (for file I/O)

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, thread-safety

Tensorflow code uses methods for file I/O that are different than python builtin methods.
According to the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py), it is useful as

> "File I/O wrappers without thread locking"

I am not sure on what occasions it is useful and when it shouldn't be used.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This comment:

> File I/O wrappers without thread locking

...is a particularly unhelpful description for TensorFlow's [`tf.gfile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile) module!

The main roles of the `tf.gfile` module are:

1. To provide an API that is close to Python's [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) objects, *and*
2. To provide an implementation based on TensorFlow's [C++ `FileSystem` API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cef828056cb70bbc180577e6f505dfd7235ab48/tensorflow/core/platform/file_system.h).

The C++ `FileSystem` API supports multiple file system implementations, including local files, Google Cloud Storage (using a `gs://` prefix), and HDFS (using an `hdfs://` prefix). TensorFlow exports these as `tf.gfile` so that you can uses these implementations for saving and loading checkpoints, writing TensorBoard logs, and accessing training data (among other uses). However, if all of your files are local, you can use the regular Python file API without any problem.

Comment: in the case all my files are local will I get any computational advantage by using [`tf.gfile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/GFile)?

Comment: No, probably not.

Comment: @martianwars But you probably won't have any noticeable performance degradation either. The point, as I understand, is that you can have a single API as an abstraction for several different persistent storage systems, so if one day you want to save to HDFS, it's just a parameter change. Because it's so convenient, I actually use this API even when I'm *not* using TensorFlow for building models/NNs.

Comment: It would be great if `gfile` was a separate Python-package s.t. we can use it in places where we don't need the rest of Tensorflow.

Comment: Got to agree with @StefanFalk. I have some simple containers as part of my ML pipeline that simply move things around in GCP buckets. I use the `gfile` module for this since it's so convenient, but adding the whole of tensorflow bloats these containers massively