# what's the difference between tf.gfile.GFile().read() and cv2.imread() when it is about reading images

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

When working with TensorFlow (image classification for example), sometimes images are loaded using `cv2.imread(image)` and other times they are loaded using `tf.gfile.GFile(image, 'rb').read()`.

Are there any differences between `cv2.imread(image)` and `tf.gfile.GFile(image, 'rb').read()` when using them with TensorFlow?

**Edit:**
My question here is about performances and maintaining image accuracy (since both of them do the job).

Comment: look to this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256938/what-does-tf-gfile-do-in-tensorflow

Comment: @Andy_101, I know that tf.gfile is used to load files, my question is, in other words, why not using `cv2.imread()` since we're loading images?

Answer (score 0):

tf.gfile is basicly to use a less-convensional filesystem such as HDFS etc...
cv2.imread(image) is for local filesystem usage.

Comment: oh ya one more thing.. i thought this was deprecated right??

Comment: No, just SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED: (position), as written in the documentation.